# How do computers calculate the log of a value?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algorithms, logarithms

I'm not sure if this question belongs on `StackOverflow` or here (please let me know if the former, and i'll delete this and ask there), but I was wondering how the `log` or `ln` of a value is calculated computationally with accuracy? Is some series implemented that approximates a value?

I looked into the Taylor series for the natural logarithm, but that is apparently only accurate for `0 < x < 2`, and I can't find anything else. I tried looking for source code for Java's `Math#log` function as well to see what algorithm they implemented, but couldn't find any since it's implemented in a native language rather than in Java.

Comment: The [first link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61209/what-algorithm-is-used-by-computers-to-calculate-logarithms) in the "related section" seems to answer this.

Comment: But, to address your concern in the second paragraph: choose $n$ so that $x/2^n<2$. Then compute $\log(x/2^n)$. You can then find $\log x$ by $\log(x/2^n)=\log x- n\log (1/2)$. You might even choose $n$ larger to obtain better and quicker approximations.

Comment: Thank you! I don't know why I didn't think of that earlier. I was looking for an algorithm to calculate this so that I can implement it myself, and this is perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the computer stores a floating point number as $a \times 2^b$ for $1 \le a \lt 2$ and $b$ an integer then $\log_e (a \times 2^b) = \log_e (a) +  b \times \log_e(2)$.

For example you can use the Taylor series for  $\log_e (1+x)$ to find $\log_e (a)$ and can store $\log_e(2)$ as a constant.