# Write number as a power of 10

Tags: complex-numbers, computational-mathematics

Just to clarify, I'm **not** interested in Standard Form/Scientific notation.
Is it possible to write a number as a power of ten, so that for example it would look like this?

```
34677534678753577 = 10^36.864
```

Something like that, I'm aware that the example isn't correct, I'm just using it to show how it should look.

If it is possible, how do I calculate the power?

I have spent much time researching this, but I only ever find stuff on scientific notation

Thanks

Comment: That's what logarithms do.  Specifically, if you have some number $N$ then you can write $$N=10^{log_{10}N}$$

Comment: Logarithms are even built into Excel. Use "=LOG(value,10)" I get: 34,677,534,678,753,577 = 10^ 16.540 048 214 713 3. For the actual algorithm, see: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61209/what-algorithm-is-used-by-computers-to-calculate-logarithms

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use what's called a logarithm with a base of 10 (as you want it to be a power of 10). For your given example:

$\log(34677534678753577)=16.54$

So

$34677534678753577=10^{16.54}$

or, more accurately,

$34677534678753577=10^{\log(34677534678753577)}$

Comment: I think you computed natural logs?  Anyway, it is clear that the $log_{10}$ of the given number is a lot smaller than $38$.

Comment: @lulu you're right! Sorry about that. I've fixed it now.

Comment: Thanks this is very helpful!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is what logarithms are. The logarithm (to base $10$) of a (positive) number $a$ is defined as the $x$ such that $10^x = a$. On writes $x = \log_{10}(a)$. Many calculators and programming languages will have this function. Note though that the default base might not be $10$.

Note that logarithms exists only for positive numbers (except you  want to use complex numbers in the technical sense, that is you have a square-root of $-1$ etc).

For further details you can see the [Wikipedia page on logarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm), or many other source on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write a number as a power of ten it's easy to use just the definition of logarithm: take a number N that you want to write as a power of ten; then for definition you have    N=10^log(N)   where the base of the logarithm is obviously 10. Notice that N needn't to be a natural, but can be any of the positive reals. You can even use another base and write N as a power of any positive real number (except for 1). Maybe you would like a more algorithmic answer but it's just a computational problem to find the actual value of log(N).

Answer (score 1):

You want to have some number in the form $b^x$ for some exact values of $b$ and $x$. A [logarithm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Logarithm.html) for a base $b$ is defined such that it is an [inverse](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseFunction.html) for $b^x$, i.e. if you have some $x$, and take $b$ to the $x$-th power, you can take the logarithm for base $b$ of the resulting number to have your $x$ back (at least for positive $b$ and real $x$ under the normal definitions subject to useful conventions).

You have some number $34677534678753577=b^x$ and you set $b=10$.

That yields an equation in one variable:
$$10^x=34677534678753577,$$
from which you can find $x$.

See what you have: you have got some number $x$, that the $10$ on the left is taken to the power of. So to have $x$ back, you need to *reverse* this process, i.e. take the logarithm for base $10$ of $10^x$, which is (you know) is equal to $34677534678753577$, that is:

$$x=\log_{10}(34677534678753577).$$

[Loading this *exact* result to Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log_10%2834677534678753577%29) will give you the approximate numerical value, if you desire:
$$\log_{10}(34677534678753577)\approx16.5400482147133085741294552031403205644432748544.$$

Please notice that this decimal representation never ends, and is never infinitely accurate.

You can also use a scientific calculator, like [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7x4a.jpg), to calculate an approximate value. If you cannot use yours to select the desired base for the logarithm, you can always first calculate the natural (base $e\approx2.718281828459$, usually goes as a $\log$ without a subscript or as $\ln$) logarithm, and then divide the resulting number by $\log(10)$ to have your $\log_{10}$ (the logarithm for base $10$).

Comment: Ah right, thanks, that's very helpful!