# Algorithm for numerically calculating $\log x$

Tags: computational-mathematics

It was while fiddling yesterday that I came up with this rather pretty approximation:

$$\log x = \frac{1}{2\epsilon}(x^{\epsilon}-x^{-\epsilon})+\mathcal{O}(\epsilon^2)$$

To be more precise,

$$\log x = \frac{1}{2\epsilon}(x^{\epsilon}-x^{-\epsilon})+\frac{1}{6}\epsilon^2(\log x)^3+\frac{1}{5!}\epsilon^4(\log x)^5+\mathcal{O}(\epsilon^6)$$

The expansion most elegantly results from looking at $f_x(\epsilon)=x^{\epsilon}$ which has derivatives $f_x^{(n)}(\epsilon)=(\log x)^nx^{\epsilon}$, and Taylor expanding about $\epsilon=0$.

Computationally, use the following algorithm:

0) Common to most algorithms is to divide $x$ by $2$ until $x$ is between $1$ and $2$, subtracting $\log 2$ from the answer each time. Use this as our starting point, i.e. $x \in (1,2)$

1) Multiply $x$ with itself to get $x^2$, then $x^2$ with itself etc to get $y=x^{2^n}$ in $n$ multiplications.

2) Calculating $a_1=\displaystyle \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}(y-1/y)$ then requires 3 more operations. $\log x=a_1+\mathcal{O}(2^{-2n})$, where for large $n$, $\mathcal{O}(2^{-2n}) \leq \frac{(\log 2)^3}{6}2^{-2n} \approx \frac{2^{-2n}}{20}$.

We could stop here: in $n+3$ multiplications we have generated roughly $2n+4$ bits of accuracy, i.e. roughly $2$ bits per operation. But we can do this:

3) Can use $a_1$ as an approximation for $\log x$ in the expansion. For sufficiently accurate $a_1$ this is valid and have $\log x =a_1+\frac{2^{-2n}}{6} (a_1)^3+\mathcal{O}(2^{-4n})$, where $\mathcal{O}(2^{-4n}) \leq \frac{(\log2)^4}{120} 2^{-4n} \approx \frac{2^{-4n}}{800}$.

So in $n+9$ operations generate $4n+9$ bits of accuracy. So for 53 bits of accuracy (roughly 16 decimal places) can take $n=11$ and use $20$ operations. I don't know exactly how good this is but it seems decent to me. For reference, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61209/what-algorithm-is-used-by-computers-to-calculate-logarithms) question for some info on how it's done.

The question is, for those more knowledgeable than me, is this actually any good?

Comment: Take a look at [CORDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CORDIC), a set of algorithms to compute several transcendental functions cheaply. The page cites mostly trigonometric functions, but the references also handle logarithms. They made handheld "scientific" calculators possible.

Comment: Step 2 in your algorithm seems to using $\epsilon=2^n$, which is, in general, a large number, but the "pretty approximation" seems to require $\epsilon\approx0$.

Comment: @BarryCipra you are quite right, you'd need square roots as opposed to squares that I am using so as to get $2^{-n}$ and not $2^n$ (small confusion on my part). I guess that closes the question, unless there's a very efficient way of calculating $x^{2^{-n}}$

Comment: hence you proved that computing $x^\epsilon$ is as hard as computing $\ln x$   (computing the $N$ first digits of their decimal representation)